# Amazon pay return the error "Place select a payment method"

Tags: magento2, amazon-payment

Amazon pay, when I select amazon pay on one step check out page by default select amazon pay but when I place order error comes "Please select a payment method". But if I refresh the page with Ctrl+f5 then the order is placed.
I am using  Magento 2.2.5

Comment: check these two link for make sure something not missing in configuration [link1](https://amzn.github.io/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/index.html) [link2](https://amzn.github.io/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/configuration.html)

Comment: Yes I match all setting all are correct